# Android Studio: List.of() 'Call requires API level...'

Tags: android, list, android-studio, lint, android-api-levels

I'm trying to use the `List.of()` method in one of my Android Studio projects but I'm running into this lint error when writing it:

```
Call requires API level 30(current min is 21):`java.util.List#of`
```

Note: I have already found a new solution that I haven't seen in other answers regarding this topic so I'm going to post it below to let others know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by adding the following annotation on top of the method that calls the `List.of()` method:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
```

This annotation specifies that the API level must be at least 30(which is what `R` represents).
Check the [Android Version Codes Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES) for the appropriate version code for your use case.

Here is the full method:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that while this gets rid of the compiler error, you will need more than this to get past the problem. Specifically, you need to use `List.of()` only on Android 11 and higher devices; the error indicates that your app is supporting devices older than that.